# How to grant all mysql 8.0 privileges to debezium in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, debezium

I tried the below command

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT, RELOAD, SHOW DATABASES, REPLICATION SLAVE, 
REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'debezium' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbz';
```

It gave the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'dbz'' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grant all privileges use [GRANT ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

```
GRANT ALL  ON *.* TO 'debezium'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbz';
```

You are missing the host in your query I added `%` you can log in from anywhere, change it based on your needs.